# RAID Controller - SSD is listed, but not available in Windows

Tags: raid, dell, ssd

This is the PowerEdge Expandable RAID Controller von LSI Corp.

There are 5 HDD running in a raid 5 and raid 1.

The SSD isnt supposed to be in any RAID activies, I just want it to pass through and show up in Windows. Its not listed in disc management but in the configuration mask of the RAID.

Its listed as Ready, whereas the RAID drives are online. The configuration parameters for this drive are very limited, I can only configure the LED to on/off and declare the drive as **hotswap**.

*How can I make it accessible in Windows?*

Comment: I'd say it's impossible if the configuration you say (LED on/off or hotswap) are the only possibilities. Some controlles can pass-through single disks or create JBODs with only one, but I don't know if that's the case with yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RAID controllers have two operating modes: RAID and IT (internal target). In the latter mode, the controller acts as a HBA (host bus adapter). In IT mode, it passes through drives directly. In RAID mode it only passes through virtual drives, which are RAID arrays configured on the controller.

Since you already have RAID on the controller, it cannot run in IT mode without breaking the RAID, so it cannot directly pass through a single disk. The workaround here is to configure the disk as a single-disk RAID 0 or JBOD.

Note: there might be controllers out there which can do both, but my experience with LSI cards is that it is either one or the other.